When i don't give the optional suffixIcon to my customTextField the hintText also not visible
Text field code:

calling text field:

When i don't give the optional suffixIcon to my customTextField the hintText also not visible.
But when i give the suffixIcon hintText is visible. How can i solve this ?
result:

Want to visible the hintText with out giving any suffixIcon in the customTextField

There's no correlation between the suffix icon and the hint text.
But, i think there's a confusion with that because you are setting hint text and a label together.
as long as both of hint text and the label have the same value  'Password'
Remove either hint text or the label. use one of them
